# WebRTC control audio playback on android mobile device - chrome broswer

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, html5-audio

Android Chrome V(50.0.2661.89) has webRTC support. So i'm trying to set up Webrtc call between Mobile chrome browser and Desktop. All works good. But on Android mobile (Samsung S4, all event few more brands). `audio output is coming on both Ear piece and External speaker`. I could not control the output audio to playback only on Ear piece. Like normal mobile calls.
`<audio>` tag has ability to set playback device id by using this `HTMLMediaElement.setSinkId(sinkId).then(function() { ... })` but in mobile chrome its not enabled. 
If it try to get all media devices. it gives only 1 kind audio output as `default`. I know this possible in native android app, But did anyone succeed in getting this playback control on mobile browser?  Please post your comments if you have any idea on this.

I've attached by mobile chrome console for reference.
[image]

Comment: `setSinkId` in not available in android chrome because Android have't provided that API yet. Reply from chrome team [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617221#c1)

Comment: Moto G5 and g5+ comes with ear piece and speaker on a same output so this won't be an issue for this device :P

Comment: The funny thing that they implemented `enumateDevices` but not `setSinkId`)) Btw this is not related to webrtc, webrtc is not even aware of your video, it only accepts stream.