# sipml5 mobile broswer use speakers instead of loud speaker

Tags: webrtc, sipml5

Guy, we are using sipml5 for web calling. As we need voice through speaker instead of loud speaker on mobile browser. can anyone please let me know how to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its in chrome then refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589959/webrtc-control-audio-playback-on-android-mobile-device-chrome-broswer

Comment: Good question, but I don't thing that there is any solution.